# How to restrict Keyboard Enter key not to allow input in the next line (TextField in Android Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

In Android emulator, entering input using Computer Keyboard, but the "Enter" key on my keyboard should take the input and do the action. Instead, the input is allowing me in the next line, and keep on continuing to the next line (as a new line character). Please suggest me your answers in Android Jetpack Composable of TextField element.

Comment: make it `singleLine = true`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hey you can use `singleLine = true` in text field, To perform any custom actions on click of Done/Enter Key in keyboard you can use something like

```
    TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {text = it},
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { /* do something */},
    onGo = { /* do something */},
    onNext = { /* do something */},
    onPrevious = { /* do something */},
    onSearch = { /* do something */},
    onSend = { /* do something */})
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add **`singleLine = true`** to avoid the new line.

Also you can use the **`onKeyEvent`** modifier to intercept the ENTER and do a custom action. You can apply the same action also to the Done Key in keyboard using the `KeyboardActions` attribute.

Something like:

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {text = it},
    singleLine = true ,
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
        onDone = { /* do something */}
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.key == Key.Enter){
            /* do something */
            true
        }
        false
    }
)
```